# How to solve "oauth_signature passed was not valid" when uploading videos with vimeo gem?

Tags: ruby, vimeo

I've wasted several hours trying to figure out how to get all the credentials I need to update my own videos on Vimeo using the [vimeo gem](https://github.com/matthooks/vimeo). I understand that I'm supposed to manually authorize my own app to my own account. I followed the instructions in the [readme](https://github.com/matthooks/vimeo/blob/master/README.markdown):

```
base = Vimeo::Advanced::Base.new(App.vimeo[:consumer_key], App.vimeo[:consumer_secret])
request_token = base.get_request_token
```

Then, I visit `base.authorize_url` and I see `Allow "App" to access your Vimeo account?`. I press "Allow", and I see a code that looks like `unicorn-weipo`. I assume that's the `oauth_verifier`. Vimeo doesn't send me to the url I specified in my app settings. Nor do I see anything else in the page that tells me what my `oauth_token` is. So, I guess my `oauth_token` is the `request_token`'s `token`. I try that:

```
base = Vimeo::Advanced::Base.new(App.vimeo[:consumer_key], App.vimeo[:consumer_secret])
access_token = base.get_access_token(request_token.token, request_token.secret, 'unicorn-weipo')
```

So far, so good. So let's save the token and secret of the `access_token`:

```
user_token = access_token.token
user_secret = access_token.secret
```

Let's do something simple first and list all videos (by the way, the readme says `get_videos` but it seems to be `get_all` now):

```
video = Vimeo::Advanced::Video.new(App.vimeo[:consumer_key], App.vimeo[:consumer_secret], :token => user_token, :secret => user_secret)
video.get_all('user10513902')
```

Response looks good:

```
{"generated_in"=>"0.0227", "stat"=>"ok", "videos"=>{"on_this_page"=>"0", "page"=>"1", "perpage"=>"50", "total"=>"0", "video"=>[]}}
```

Now I want to upload something:

```
upload = Vimeo::Advanced::Upload.new(App.vimeo[:consumer_key], App[:consumer_secret], :token => user_token, :secret => user_secret)
f = File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'fixtures', 'sample.avi'))
upload.upload(f)
```

But then I see this:

```
Vimeo::Advanced::RequestFailed: 303: Invalid signature, explanation: The oauth_signature passed was not valid
```

How do I fix this? I want to be able to upload videos.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems Vimeo sometime [put a pejorative adverb here] returns an invalid oauth_signature error for different reasons.